# Crosstab applying calculated functions by default

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a crosstab made out of the dataset as follows

[image]

I expect no calculation function on the measure columns. But, the report when it runs always takes the highest by default and the result looks as below. How do I get the report to just give the pivoted data and not perform any calculation on the measures?

[image]

I expect the data to look as shown in the picture below

[image: http://i66.tinypic.com/adnac7.jpg]

Please find below the related jrxml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="crosstabmeasure" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e47b3f7d-1e00-4702-a900-be50a229f085">
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.time.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.Date"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="set1" uuid="0271cb46-f184-47b2-8ab3-e6ee96ea33ef">
        <parameter name="Locale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="UtcOffSet" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, inter.*
from internatioinlization inter, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
where 1 = case when  1 = 1 and $P{Locale} is not null and $P{UtcOffSet} is not null then 1  else 0 end]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="rank" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="col3" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
        <field name="col4" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Locale" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="UtcOffSet" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, inter.*
from internatioinlization inter, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
where 1 = case when  1 = 1 and $P{Locale} is not null and $P{UtcOffSet} is not null then 1  else 0 end]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="rank" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="211" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="211" uuid="6c5ccb8a-50fc-4158-b2ba-88d864aa1e43">
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabParameter name="Locale">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("Locale")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="UtcOffSet" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("UtcOffSet")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="set1" uuid="d255c9b9-fbb2-420a-8ef5-3236098654f1">
                            <datasetParameter name="Locale">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Locale}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="UtcOffSet">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UtcOffSet}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <rowGroup name="col11" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="86c09a7f-46b5-4d2f-ba87-715f99d832a8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col11}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="94fca0ea-1572-4d42-85d9-b06f92c73b6e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col11]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col41" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" uuid="137ef406-6a2e-4629-9d38-4858c4a5ae2c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col41}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="5c71211d-f1db-4911-8923-2bdb208ddb99"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col41]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col2_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col3_MEASURE1" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="861d0d3a-d774-4b0c-ae7d-ace315bf305c"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="163ed502-e753-444a-942d-832d84da0a5f"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1} != null ? DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale($P{Locale}.split("-")[0], $P{Locale}.split("-")[1])).format(DateUtils.addMinutes($V{col3_MEASURE1},$P{UtcOffSet})) : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2576b9e2-3bba-40e3-aa15-5f4f0aada549"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a111181f-b60f-4afd-8292-9e260c1b9ce2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9adf6c9c-acee-4673-8b70-a376e7d1cbb4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9baedeed-4770-4153-b639-afc0965e9467"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a2805e0a-080d-42be-ad86-a7e8e666f571"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="c485f69d-91e1-4b19-a8ab-bdbfa3cafcc6"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What data are you waiting as a result (it is better to post the image)?

Comment: Apologies for pasting the wrong jrxml. I have updated the new jrxml in the main question. Please have a look at the new code. Also, I have attached a picture containing the requirement of how the data must look

Comment: `I expect no calculation function on the measure columns` - It is usual behaviour to show some aggregation results for groups in crosstab. You have some misunderstanding of how the crosstab is working. You can add columns with col2 and col3 and play with hiding headers and showing this values. In some cases the placing of subreport/list component is a good variant

Comment: Hi Alex, Even when 'No Calculation Function' is added, the aggregation still happens. I understand that crosstabs are meant to show aggregations in general. Since, there is an option to not calculate any aggregation, I wanted to understand why this option was not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent bucketing/aggregation for the col1 row group, you can add a second row group (with no header cells) that has distinct values for each record.  For instance:

```
        <rowGroup name="RecNo" width="0">
            <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                <bucketExpression>$V{REPORT_COUNT}</bucketExpression>
            </bucket>
        </rowGroup>
```